# zlib: zlib binding closed

Tags: node.js, npm-install, zlib

I am trying to upgrade node version using: **npm install npm@latest -g** command. But it is giving zlib binding closed error.

Is there a way to resolve this? 
[image: error image]

Answer (score 1):

What is your node version, I had node v6.0.0 and got the same issue, once I upgraded the node to latest the error went away. Please try using the latest node